# Structural type instead of a trait

Tags: scala

I'm quite new to scala and I am working myself trough a tutorial: http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2013/08/02/akka-and-spray/

At some point it comes to testing and it tells that one could get over the inheritance requirement by creating a structural type:

> ActorSystem fully implements the Core trait. However, I need to
>   implement the Core trait to satisfy the self-type declaration of the
>   CoreActors.
>
> I could have defined Core to be structural type, in which case,I would
>   not have to worry about implementing Core here. If you want to try it
>   out, remove the trait Core { ... } and replace it with
>
> package object core {   type Core = { def system: ActorSystem } }
>   Here, the Core type is a structural type, which says that Core is
>   anything which contains the system: ActorSystem member.

And I don't get this - if I don't create a trait core I can not extend from it in CoreActors - I think I've missed something here. The concept of structural types is also new to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Structural types cannot be extended. They describe types not in terms of an hierarchy, but in terms of the methods it provides.

So, in the case where you have

```
type Core = { def system: ActorSystem }
```

It means that *any* type which has a method called `system` that takes no parameters and return an `ActoreSystem` will also be a `Core`.

Structural types in Scala, however, are limited in some ways. For one thing, they cannot be recursive (that is, `Core` could appear in side `Core`'s definition), which makes them useless, for example, for things like arithmetic operators.

They are also not efficient, since they are implemented through reflection.

Comment: Does that mean that 'Core' also has to be defined anyways?
So i need a trait Core anyways? The tutorial says that I could replace the trait with the structural type.

Comment: @DanielKhan No, you don't need to define `Core` as a trait.